# Java SimpleDateFormat Date Actual Result Changed

Tags: java, simpledateformat, java-time

I use the code below to change the date format of the date. But the result changes to different date, it becomes 12/27/2021. When I checked it, it says it uses Gregorian Calendar. Anyone know how to fix this.

```
        String date = "23-03-2021";
        Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY").parse(date);
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
        String paymentdate = outputFormat.format(d);
        System.out.println(paymentdate);
```

Actual:

```
12/27/2021
```

Expected:

```
03/23/2021
```

Comment: That happens because you are using upper-case `YYYY` for the year, instead of lower-case `yyyy`. Upper-case `Y` means "week year", which is not exactly the same as calendar year. See the [API docs of `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: If at all possible you should stop using `Date` which is poorly designed and use the java.time classes such as `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: @Jesper thanks! it solved my problem. Should I use also lowercase MM?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: No, do not use lower-case `mm`, because that means minutes instead of months. It's all in the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) that I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `YYYY` instead of `yyyy`. I tried your code snippet and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY` because `Y` represents the **week of year** or **week year** whereas `y` represents only **year**.

According to [Java Docs on Week Of Year and Week Year](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year) :

> A week year is in sync with a WEEK_OF_YEAR cycle. All weeks between
> the first and last weeks (inclusive) have the same week year value.
> Therefore, the first and last days of a week year may have different
> calendar year values.

Modified code :

```
String date = "23-03-2021";
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(date);
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String paymentdate = outputFormat.format(d);
System.out.println(paymentdate);
```

Output :

```
03/23/2021
```

---

Don't use `java.util.Date` as it is deprecated and it will be removed in the future. Better use classes from `java.time` package.

Equivalent code using `java.time` classes :

```
String date = "23-03-2021";
TemporalAccessor d = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(date);
String paymentdate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy").format(d);
System.out.println(paymentdate);
```

Output :

```
03/23/2021
```